# Dataset to build customer service bot

Tags: data-request

I am building a customer service virtual assistant bot. It is on the tech support side of customer service.

Is there a way to get sample dataset that I can use to build it?

Answer (score 0):

Some open data sets involving conversations i came across some time back. Personally i have not explored the dataset.

https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~cristian/Cornell_Movie-Dialogs_Corpus.html

http://dataset.cs.mcgill.ca/ubuntu-corpus-1.0/

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52375&from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdownloads%2F6096d3da-0c3b-42fa-a480-646929aa06f1%2F

Other option, Movie subtitles.